# Android inapp billing: how to get the correct language in the Google Checkout window displayed in my app?

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have got some inapp billing in my Android app.

When the user clicks on the buy button in my app, the Google Checkout window is displayed (where the user can choose its credit card and click on "Buy and download").

My problem is that I localized/internationalized the message appearing in this window via the Android Market developer console but:

- on one of my apps, the language displayed in the Google Checkout window is always English (even if I added all the other possible langages)
- on one of my other apps, the language displayed in the Google Checkout window is Spanish (even if my phone is setup in French and I added FR in the Android Market developer console (in the inapp billing menu))

How to solve this issue ??

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting this too, looks like a bug in the Market application. Besides trying to report it, there is not much you can do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I did at the moment is to leave only the english language in the console. I prefer that my user always get a message in English and not a message in Chinese (if they are not chinese...). If anyone has got a solution, tell us !